# In C language binary file io

Tags: c, file, io, binary

if I input a binary file to array buf, why do I have to input it by (void*) ??
and why do I have to write it by (void*)?? please observe this code and please explain this code to me. (I just copy this code from my book)

```
int main(void) {
FILE * src = fopen("a.png", "rb");
FILE * des = fopen("b.png", "wb");

char buf[20];
int readCnt;

if (src == NULL || des == NULL) {
    puts("File open failed");
    return -1;
}

while (1) {
    readCnt = fread((void*)buf, 1, sizeof(buf), src);

    if (readCnt < sizeof(buf)) {
        if (feof(src) != 0) {
            fwrite((void*)buf, 1, readCnt, des);
            puts("File copy complete");
            break;
        }
        else
            puts("File copy Failed");

        break;
    }
    fwrite((void*)buf, 1, sizeof(buf), des);
}
fclose(src);
fclose(des);
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Is this book old? There is no need to cast to `void *`, every pointer in [tag:c] is convertible from `void *` and back without casting

Comment: uint64_t buf[20] would need to read more void*, but you can do file io with anything really

Answer (score 2):

Because `fread()` & `fwrite()` are **generic function** for reading and writing binary data into file `irrespective` of their `data type`.

man page of fwrite() says,

```
size_t fwrite(const void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb,
                     FILE *stream);
```

what is first arguement, its `const void *ptr` means its expecting address. it can be any variable address int or char or any other data type .

Answer (score 0):

The cast to `void*` is because this is what the functions expect. See [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fread/) and [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fwrite/).

Your code will compile without this cast, because cast to `void*` is not necessary (see quote below), but I guess the author wanted to be exact as possible.

**6.3.2.3 Pointers**

> 1 A pointer to void may be converted to or from a pointer to any incomplete or object type. A pointer to any incomplete or object type may be converted to a pointer to void and back again; the result shall compare equal to the original pointer.

Another thing - `(void*)` is a good way to suppress compiler warnings. It may not be a good thing to begin with (warning are there for a reason), but if need be, this is a simple way to ignore wrong pointer type in function arguments.

Comment: IMHO it's bad style to have redundant pointer casts. Converting to/from `void *` is implicit for good reasons...

Comment: @FelixPalmen I Don't know. I see it a lot. A function expects `int*` but instead is provided a `unsigned int*`. The fix I see many times for this is `(void*)`. About bad style - totally agree. I don't write such code

Comment: The only "good" reason for a pointer to pointer cast is bad design.

Comment: Indeed. But sadly not all of us write code top to bottom. Upon seeing such a problem that stems from bad design - this is a simple fix

Comment: @JensGustedt Or printing a pointer (more general, passing a generic pointer to a variadic function). Or aliasing with `char *` to examine the representation. But I  agree you should avoid pointer casts because anywhere you need them is a place in the code that needs extra care not to violate strict aliasing etc. -- that's my primary argument against [casting the `malloc()` result](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2371524).

Answer (score 0):

This is so that you can pass any pointer type. So for example, if you want to write a structure like for example

```
struct point {
    int x;
    int y;
};

struct point my_point = {1, 2};
FILE *file = fopen("sample-file.bin", "w");
if (file != NULL) {
    // Normally check that this returns the number of
    // written items
    fwrite(&my_point, 1, sizeof(my_point), file);
    fclose(file);
}
```

would work, and when you open the file for reading you can `fread(&my_point ...)` too.

Note that casting to `void *` is not necessary in [c](/questions/tagged/c), nor is it needed to cast from `void *` to another pointer type, for instance

```
char *example = malloc(size + 1);
```

is perfectly valid and `malloc()` returns `void *`.

Answer (score 0):

This should probably be a comment but i don't have the reputation for that. In your code:

> `if (src == NULL || des == NULL) {
>       puts("File open failed");
>       return -1;
>   }`

There is a chance that either src or des may have been opened correctly and therefore should have `fclose();` called for it.

Something like:

```
if (src == NULL || des == NULL) 
{
      if(src)
      {
        fclose(src);
      }
      if(des)
      {
        fclose(des);
      }
      puts("File open failed");
      return -1;
  }
```

would be better.